# Inherit from jQuery UI dialog and call overridden method

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, inheritance, overriding

The simple code below describes my question (at least I hopse so):

```
$.widget("ui.mydialog", $.ui.dialog, {
  _create: function() {
    // How to call _create method of dialog?
  }
});
```

I tried to call `$.ui.dialog.prototype._create()` from within the above create method, but get the below error in Firebug:

```
this.element is undefined
this.originalTitle = this.element.attr('title');
jquery...5667348 (line 5864)
```

How else can I call that "super" method?

jQuery UI version 1.8.8

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I guess I just found a solution ... `$.ui.dialog.prototype._create.call(this);`

The full code:

```
$.widget("ui.ajaxdialog", $.ui.dialog, {
  _create: function() {
    // Your code before calling the overridden method.
    $.ui.dialog.prototype._create.call(this);
    // Your code after calling the overridden method.
  }
});
```

Comment: For jqueryui 1.9x you can simply do:  `this._super('_create');`  the above solution is also still valid.

Comment: Interesting. Simple `this._super()` in `_create` function will also do. Then it is the matter of taste probably.

Comment: Actually, according to the docs (http://api.jqueryui.com/jQuery.widget/#method-_super), _super doesn't have any arguments. It just magically knows where you are.

Comment: Every time you call any of the "overridable" function "this._super" is changed to function, which knows about which "super" it actually refers to.