# Extending widgets in Jquery UI with redefining parent methods

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, widget, jquery-ui-dialog, extending

I try to extend UI dialog according to [documentation](http://jqueryui.com/docs/Developer_Guide) (UI version 1.8.16):

```
(function($) {
    $.widget('ui.mydialog', $.extend(true, $.ui.dialog.prototype, {
        _create: function() {
            return $.Widget.prototype._create.apply(this, arguments);
        }
    }));
})(jQuery);

$(function() {
    $('div#dialog').mydialog();
});
```

Executing of this code causes JS error: "this.uiDialog is undefined".

And if try to override the _init() method there are no errors, but parent method call takes no effect.

I'm confused.. Which way is legal to extending for e.g. put some custom initialize code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this post would solve your question: [Inherit from jQuery UI dialog and call overridden method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789493/inherit-from-jquery-ui-dialog-and-call-overridden-method).

In short, if you want to build a widget inheriting jQuery UI Dialog, you can do this:

```
(function($) {
    $.widget("ui.mydialog", $.ui.dialog, {
        _create: function() {
            $.ui.dialog.prototype._create.call(this);
        }
    });

})(jQuery);
```

See this in action: http://jsfiddle.net/william/RELxP/.

---

This tutorial will enlighten you: http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/12138135/Widget%20factory. In short, `$.Widget` is the base widget object. Even though it has a `_create` function, it by default does nothing, leaving the initialisation code to the subclass. Take a look at this updated example: http://jsfiddle.net/william/RELxP/1.

Comment: Thanks. It's really help. But i'm wondering why doesn't work extending approach from official documentation:

Comment: which part of the official doco are you talking about? The word "extend" doesn't come up once in the jQuery UI Developer Guide.

Comment: This one: http://jqueryui.com/docs/Developer_Guide
Yes, "extend" - is my innovation;)
But I mentioned about this approach: $.Widget.prototype...

Comment: i'm got confused with jqueryui doc. you help me to figure it out. thanks a lot, man!

Comment: Is this still the recommended way? Or would it be better to do `this._super(this.options)`?

Comment: Works, but it's obsolete and too verbose now

Answer (score 5):

From jQuery 1.9 and on, if you want to add functionality to a widget and don't want to replace the existing function, after you do your code call the parent method. To do this, instead of what William Niu suggests, you can simply do this:

```
_create: function()
{
    // Custom code here

    // Call the _create method of the widget
    this._super();
}
```

This applies to all existing methods. (eg `_setOption`, `_trigger` etc)

Comment: Yes, this._super() will call the method in the parent with the same name: https://learn.jquery.com/jquery-ui/widget-factory/extending-widgets/ . Good answer

Comment: This saved my life. This is what the doc says about extending the existing `open` method: `Since dialogs automatically open by default, "open" will be logged when this code runs`, but they don't call `this._super()` which results in the same error as OP was experiencing.

Answer (score 1):

I posted a simple example of extending a jQueryUI Dialog using the Widget factory.

http://jsfiddle.net/Artistan/jWUGZ/

This example extends a dialog to create a simple loading modal.

Comment: A little late, don't you think?

Comment: Yep, a little late for OP but not for the community ;)