# Using jQueryUI 's widget factory to extend dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I'm using jqueryUI's widget factory to extend jqUI's dialog widget. I've setup the simplest widget I can think of. It does nothing, just inherits from dialog. Still I've not been able to get it to work.

I have a fiddle demonstrating it here: [View Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mFWs4/)

Here's the test markup:

```
<div id="a">hello</div>
<div id="b">bye</div>
```

Here's the javascript:

```
(function ($, undefined)
{
    var o =  //Widget prototype
    {
        options: {},

        _create: function ()  {},

        destroy: function ()
        {
            $.Widget.prototype.destroy.call(this);    
        },

        _setOption: function (key, value)
        {
            $.Widget.prototype._setOption.apply(this, arguments);
        },
    };

    //Run jQuery's widget factory to create the widget
    $.widget('cs.csDialog', $.ui.dialog, o);
} (jQuery));

//Test it out
$("#a").dialog(); //Works
$("#b").csDialog(); //Fails
```

Inside jqUI I get the following error:
**this.uiDialog is undefined**

I can't see what I've done wrong. I'd greatly appreciate any help. Thank you.

Comment: Is it because you have overridden the _create function?

Comment: Thank you! Yes...I see I need to call the base _create function inside my overwritten one to get the original functionality. Makes sense. Would you like to make your comment an answer so I can give you credit for it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason it is not working, as I wrote in my comment, is because you overwrote the _create function.

Answer (score 0):

Just for future readers, here is how to call the base _create function as mentioned in the comments. Answered inspired by [William Niu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7458579/2746057) answer for a different question.

```
   _create: function() {
       $.ui.dialog.prototype._create.call(this);
   }
```

Another way to call the base _create is to add the following line of code in your method:

```
this._super();
```